# How to use array destructuring on object property?

Tags: javascript, eslint

```js
const arr = [1,2];

const respond = {};

respond.obj = arr[0];
```

The above code giving me eslint error `prefer-destructuring`. I understand what's it trying to tell but I'm wondering about my above case is possible?

Below is what I thought it might be working but apparently no

```js
const [respond.a,b] = arr;
```

Is there any similar approach that gives me something as above?

Comment: Using destructuring for that is overkill. You should probably disable that rule.

Comment: I think it's because of the `arr[0]`, when it thinks you should do `const [one, two] = [1,2]` and `respond.obj = one`. However I think often the prefers-destructuring rule is a bit silly, and personally I'd make it a warning rather than an error. I wouldn't make your code unreadable just to make eslint happy

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
const arr = [1,2];

const respond = {};

[respond.obj] = arr;

console.log(respond);
```

Or you can disable the rule for this line:

```
respond.obj = arr[0]; // eslint-disable-line prefer-destructuring
```

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that you have to destructure the array in the first line.

```
const [firstNumber, secondNumber] = [1,2];

const respond = {};

respond.obj = firstNumber;

console.log(respond);
```